# Connected Y-shaped intersection using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I would like to achieve the following intersection between 3 pipes:

[image: desired outcome]

The final goal is to then extrude the centre triangle face outwards, and apply a subdivision modifier to get a smooth spike shape:

[image: intersection with spike]

My question is: **How do I create such a Y-shaped intersection with an ico sphere and geometry nodes?**

So far, I've created an ico sphere and applied a square curve profile along the edges. Next, I would like to somehow merge the intersecting profiles to create the desired intersections shown in the image above, but I have no idea how to do so.

[image: ico sphere without smooth intersections]

[image: geometry nodes setup]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE! This is a very tricky and extensive task, which requires not only a good knowledge of *Geometry Nodes*, but also a relatively large number of nodes. In any case, an answer would go beyond the scope here, I'm afraid. But I might have an idea how to solve it. May I ask what exactly you want to do with it?

Answer (score -1):

May i suggest an alternative? You could use the dul mesh method.the link below might shed some light

https://blenderartists.org/t/dual-mesh-sculptures-with-geometry-nodes/1444435?u=anurag_raturi

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/173483)

Comment: I'm sorry for that.. didn't know about the rule.will keep in mind next time